# Node.js/Express: How Do I Share or Export Mongo Database Connection To Other Modules?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to share the Mongo connection with other modules in my Node.js project. I keep getting either `undefined` or `is not a function` when attempting to use the exported client. I also had a question around detecting if the connection is in fact open before performing operations on the database.

It seems like using the `app.locals` would be the proper way to share the connection but I could not get that working either. Below is what I have at the moment. I've tried this many ways. Most of what I can find online seems to export the Mongo Node driver's method, not the connection itself. The idea is to connect once and never disconnect until the app shuts down.

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

async function connect () {
    app.locals.dbConnected = false;
    try {
        await client.connect();
        app.locals.dbConnected = true;
        module.exports = client;
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
};
```

then in another module do something like:

```
await client.db('syslogs').collection('production').insertOne(doc);
```

Is it possible to share the *connection*?

Answer (score 1):

Could do something like below:

```js
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

let __inst = null;

export default new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (__inst !== null) resolve(__inst);

  // the open event is the key here
  // like this we can handle error, close etc thru events as well
  client.open((err, mongoInst) => {
    if (err) reject(err);
    __inst = mongoInst;
    resolve(__inst);
  });
});
```

Then in other module you can use the export client like you want.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I think `.open` is a method rather than an event though? The events are available with the `client.on("serverClosed", event =>`. In any case, thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

I just got it working using `app.locals`.

index.js

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
(async () => {
    app.locals.dbConnected = false;
    try {
        await client.connect();
        console.log("Connected to DB");
        app.locals.client = client;
        app.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
          console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
})();
```

Then in my module:

```
async function index (req, res) {
  try {
    let db = req.app.locals.client.db("admin");
    await db.command({ ping: 1 });
    console.log("pinged admin database");
  }catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
  }
}
```